# How to use haskell types?

Tags: haskell, types, boolean

Really simple question, i can't for the life of me google the info :(

I have the following types:

```
type NI = Int
type Age = Int
type Balance = Int
type Person = (NI, Age, Balance)
```

How do I create a function that returns true if a person's age is over 65? I've tried:

```
retired :: Person -> Bool
retired p = p >= 65
```

It doesn't work obviously, i realise that even when i tried it. I'm stumped on something so simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as `Person` is a tuple you should pattern-match it like this:

```
retired (_,age,_) = age >= 65
```

and it should work

Answer (score 3):

`type X = Y` defines a *type alias*. In this example, `X` is defined to be the same as `Y`. Therefore, `retired :: Person -> Bool` is the same as `retired :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool`.

Then we can ask the question: how do we obtain a person's age? Well, `Person` is the same as `(Int, Int, Int)`, and we know the second element of the tuple is the person's age. Therefore, an equivalent question is: how do we obtain the second element of a 3-tuple?

This is done in Haskell by *deconstructing* the tuple, which is the opposite of *constructing* the tuple. An example of constructing a tuple is `x = (1,2,3)`. To deconstruct a tuple, we use a similar notation but flip the sides: `(a,b,c) = x`. This is the same as `(a,b,c) = (1,2,3)`, and the same as the three assignments `a = 1; b = 2; c = 3`.

Haskell allows you to use this deconstruction notation for function arguments. Therefore, `retired p = e` could be written `retired (ni, age, balance) = e`, recalling that `Person` is a 3-tuple. Now it is straight-forward that `e` should be `age >= 65`.

To elaborate further, `retired (ni, age, balance) = e` is equivalent to `retired p = let (ni, age, balance) = p in e`. This is useful to know because then function application is clearer. `retired x` is `let (ni, age, balance) = x in [x/p]e` where `[x/p]e` means "substitute *x* for *p* in *e*".

---

Another approach is to define a data type using record notation.

`data Person = Person { ni :: Int, age :: Int, balance :: Int }`

This defines a new type called `Person`, and is not the same as the 3-tuple of type `(Int, Int, Int)`. Additionally, this defines three *projection* functions `ni :: Person -> Int`, `age :: Person -> Int`, and `balance :: Person -> Int`.

Now if we implement `retired :: Person -> Bool` we can do so as `retired p = age p >= 65`, or in point-free form `retired = (>= 65) . age`.

To reconnect with the first approach, can you also use deconstruction? Absolutely. A Person is constructed as `x = Person m n p`, and so similarly can be deconstructed as `Person a b c = x`. Therefore, another definition for `retired` is `retired (Person n a b) = a >= 65`.